# Get checkbox names ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to take only selected checkboxes. I tried this.

```
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Box" value="LDL" />
    <label for="Box">LDL</label><br>
     
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Box" value="LDL" />
    <label for="Box">LDL</label><br>`enter code here`

    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Box" value="HDL" />
    <label for="Box">HDL</label><br>

<div class="button-holder d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</div>
```

This is the Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendTest(ListParams listParams)
    {

    }
```

This is the DTO

public class CheckboxParams
{
public string Box { get; set; }

```
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class ListParams
{
    public ListParams()
    {
        this.AllCheckedParams = new List<CheckboxParams>();
    }
    public List<CheckboxParams> AllCheckedParams { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DimitarKazakov, welcome to StackOverflow. Please further elaborate on what issue you faced in your question. You may read on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to update your question. Thank you.

Comment: And you should tag your question with `asp.net-core` but not `asp.net`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asp.net core, Model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix. Besides, the nested array matches the `[index].property_name` or `property_name[index].property_name`.

In your code, the name of the checkbox could not match the property in `ListParams` model. The correct way should be `AllCheckedParams[index].box`.

But for your scenario, **your model design is not correct**. The browser will only send the selected checkbox to the backend by default when form submit. If you choose the first two or last two(anyway,that is to say the index should be consecutive) checkbox, it works well. If you choose the first and third checkbox, it does not work any more. Because the name of them is `AllCheckedParams[0].box` and `AllCheckedParams[2].box`. They are not consecutive index of the array, so only the first checkbox could be matched and passed to the backend.

The correct way is that just **change your backend received data** like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendTest(string[] box)
{
}
```

If you still want to use the model, you need change the model like below:

```
public class ListParams
{
    public List<string> Box { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendTest(ListParams listParams)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlHelper class provides two extension methods to generate a  element in an ASP.NET MVC view. They are as follows:

```
CheckBox()
CheckBoxFor()
```

for creating form in razor page you can use

```
@model Student

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isActive)
```

The Html.CheckBox() is a loosely typed method which generates a  with the specified name, isChecked boolean, and HTML attributes.

```
@Html.CheckBox("isActive", true)
```